# How many natural numbers not more than $4300$ can be formed with the digits $0,1,2,3,4$ if repetitions are allowed?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many natural numbers not more than $4300$ can be formed with the digits $0,1,2,3,4$ if repetitions are allowed?

My approach was to subtract from $5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 = 675$ (total numbers which can be formed with digits $0,1,2,3,4,5$) and subtracting the greater numbers than $4300$.

Numbers greater than $4300$:

My approach in extreme left only $2$ numbers $4,5$ can come and $10,000$'s place only two numbers $3,4$ can come, in $100$'s place $5$ numbers, in ten's place $5$ numbers, in units place $5$ numbers can come. Thereby the number of ways $= 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 = 150$ ($-1$, i.e. $4300$ itself cannot be counted). However my answer is wrong.

Correct Answer is $= 575$. Please help me with the solution. I am struggling in this.

Comment: I think your approach is a little confused :) It's not very clear to me what "in extreme left only 2 numbers 4,5 can come and 10,000th place only two numbers 3,4 can come" means or where you got this idea from. It seems to disregard numbers like $1111$

Comment: Extreme Left means numbers starting with 4,5

Comment: sorry the 10000th is wrong i meant 1000th place

Comment: ... so would you say your approach accounts for each of the numbers 1, 10, 100, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000?

Comment: You want to count natural numbers *less than* or equal to $4300$.  Why are you considering digits in the ten thousands place?

Comment: yes it accounts

Comment: My approach was to subtract from 5*5*5*5*5=675(total numbers which can be formed with digits -0,1,2,3,4,5) and subtracting the greater numbers than 4300.

Comment: i.e. 675 - numbers greater than 4300

Comment: The total numbers that can be formed are $5^4 = 625$.  From the answer, I am guessing that $0$ is not considered a natural number.

Comment: yes u r correct

Comment: One error you made was including the digit $5$ in the leading decimal place since $5$ is not an available digit.

Comment: ok yes its wrong

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer, I will assume that $0$ is not considered a natural number in this context.

Each *nonnegative* integer with at most four digits that can be formed using the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ with repetition can be represented by a four-digit string by appending leading zeros as necessary when the number has fewer than four digits.  For instance, we can represent $17$ as $0017$.

Thus, if there were no restrictions on the size of the nonnegative integer, we would be able to form $5^4$ nonnegative integers since there are five ways to fill each of the four decimal places in the string.  Since these include $0000$, which represents $0$, there are $5^4 - 1$ *positive* integers that can be formed using the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ with repetition.

From these, we will subtract those greater than $4300$.

Let's first count the numbers that are *at least* $4300$ which can be formed using the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ must have a $4$ in the thousands place and either a $3$ or $4$ in the hundreds place.  We can fill the tens place in five ways and the units place in five ways. Therefore, there are $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 5$ numbers that are *at least* $4300$ that can be formed using the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ with repetition.  However, they include $4300$, so there are $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 - 1$ numbers *greater than* $4300$ that can be formed using the same digits with repetition.

Hence, there are 
$$5^4 - 1 - (1 \cdot 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 - 1) = 5^4 - 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 = 625 - 50 = 575$$
*positive* integers not greater than $4300$ that can be formed using the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ with repetition.

Comment: thnks nice explanation